# Is it worth for a Team Lead to study PGDPM in distance Education?

Tags: project-management-style

I have designated as Mobile Team Lead in a small company. But I feel that I have huge to learn apart from the daily activities I am doing .

The most Important thing I want to learn is how to communicate with client effectively and how to manage people effectively.

Will doing PGDPM(Post Graduate Diploma in Project Management) in Distance Education help me improve my skills?

Comment: Studying formal Project Management is great, and some Distance Education programs are very good. (I teach at Brandeis's Graduate Professional Studies program, for instance, albeit not in Project Management. I think our classes tend to be very good.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my opinion doing PGDPM in distance will help you in improving your skills for sure, I do agree in full time education there will be people to follow and correct you. with some extra efforts like watching respective youtube(or educational) videos and with help of your like-minded colleagues we can fill that gap.